# How to SELECT the stronger entity which is a @MappedSuperclass by the weaker entity's id using HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have the following mapped superclass which serves as a superclass to other 3 classes:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Donation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    //other irrelevant attributes

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Voucher> vouchers;

    //getters and setters
}
```

The other classes extending from `Donation` are `Adoption`, `Appointment` and `Exam`. This relationship created the following associative entities towards `Voucher`: `adoption_vouchers`, `appointment_vouchers` and `exam_vouchers`.

The current problem is that now I have to list all `Voucher` together with it's `Donation` entity. **Since I do not have specified the donation relationship in the voucher class** (because it could represent any of the 3 classes mentioned, and I can't relate to a `@MappedSuperclass`), is there a way I achieve it using HQL (retrieving something like a `Map<Donation, Voucher>`), or maybe minor changes in my structure to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HQL could look like this with below model
`SELECT a.vouchers FROM Adoption a;`

```
public enum DonationType {
  ADOPTION, APPOINTMENT, EXAM;
}

@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", 
  discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Donation {
     @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
     private DonationType type;

     @JsonIgnore
     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     private List<Voucher> vouchers;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(DonationType.ADOPTION)
public class Adoption extends Donation {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(DonationType.Exam)
public class Exam extends Donation {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(DonationType.APPOINTMENT)
public class Appointment extends Donation {
}

@Entity
public class Voucher {
   //could be single mapping just to supperclass, depends on logic what do you need
   @ManyToOne
   private Adoption adoption;

   @ManyToOne
   private Exam exam;

   @ManyToOne
   private Appointment exam;

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the 3 classes be extending from Donation?

Comment: Yeah, fixed :D It's 1 am so i've been a little sleepy

Comment: That way I can still have this `private List<Voucher> vouchers` in the Donation class? Another issue, I don't think I can have both `@MappedSuperclass` and `@Entity` annotated in Donation

Comment: Sure, having vouchers field should work. Probably yeah, I have removed @Entity from Donation.

Comment: Oh, and I can't use the enums in the `@DiscriminatorValue`, I'll have to go with the String "EXAM", "ADOPTION", etc

Comment: I've added `@Enumerated` on type. Try it, `@DiscriminatorValue` should work with enum.

Comment: I really can't, it's only accepting Strings. Maybe the @Enumerated should be somewhere else?

Comment: I've made some minor changes, but it worked like a charm! Thank you!